# Update UEFI on a Dell machine without Windows?

Tags: windows-10, uefi, updates, dell-xps

I purchased a new [XPS 8930](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/xps-8930-desktop/drivers). It is sold with Windows 10 Pro.

After browsing the licensing agreement I decided I don't agree. I'm going to sell my copy of Windows 10 Pro on the open market. I'm also going to install Linux (I verified it boots the machine).

The machine has an urgent UEFI update. It is called `XPS8930_1.1.7.exe`. It appears to be a Windows program. I don't want to use my copy of Windows and taint it for the next owner.

I searched Dell's site for a procedure to update the UEFI using Linux. I have not been able to locate it. I'm not sure it exists.

My question is, how do I update the UEFI without using Windows or tainting the copy of Windows on this machine?

Comment: Unless you're intending on selling the computer along with the Windows license, then what you want to do isn't allowed (per OEM license terms) and your license cannot be activated in a different machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to update the UEFI using Dell's procedure at [Flashing the BIOS from the F12 One-Time Boot Menu](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln305230/flashing-the-bios-from-the-f12-one-time-boot-menu).

The procedure applies to machines built around 2012 and later. It allows us to use the BIOS to read the `*.exe` file directly rather than use the old method of extracting the files, booting, and then manually flashing.

From [Flashing the BIOS from the F12 One-Time Boot Menu](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln305230/flashing-the-bios-from-the-f12-one-time-boot-menu):

> ***BIOS Update***
>
> The BIOS update file for your system can be run from inside Windows,
>   from a bootable USB key and on systems with the option you can update
>   the BIOS from \the F12 One-Time boot menu.
>
> Most Dell systems built after 2012 have this capability and you can
>   confirm by booting your system to the F12 One-Time Boot Menu to see if
>   BIOS FLASH UPDATE is listed as a boot option for your system. If the
>   option is listed then the BIOS supports this BIOS update option.